# Why does pygame.time.wait kick in before display update?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a code for a game where you slide 15 tiles to set them in order. At the end of the game, I want the screen to just wait for 5 seconds before closing (also want to give a message but that later).

When the game ends, it first pauses and then shows the last move and then closes out. Is there a lag in the display. How do I make it complete the display, and then wait. I tried reading similar posts, but couldn't quite understand.

Here is the relevant code.

```
>   def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        self._shuffle_grid()
        self._show_board()
        game_over = False
        while True:
            change = self._check_events()
            if change:
                self._show_board()
                game_over = self.end_of_game()
            if game_over:
                pygame.time.wait(5000)
                sys.exit()


    def _check_events(self):
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
        change = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    key = "U"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    key = "D"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    key = "L"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    key = "R"
                if key == "U" or "D" or "L" or "R":
                    change = self.key_check(key)
        return(change)
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried this and it worked. I still don't know how to show a message and then wait 5 seconds. Working on it.

```
    def celebrate(self):
        """ does end of game thing"""
        game_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        time_passed = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self._show_board()
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    sys.exit()
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() > time_passed + 5000:
                sys.exit()


    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        self._shuffle_grid()
        self._show_board()
        game_over = False
        while True:
            change = self._check_events()
            if change:
                game_over = self.end_of_game()
                if not game_over:               
                    self._show_board()
                else:
                    self.celebrate()
```